# Segmentation fault with vector in C++

Tags: c++, vector

I am new to C++ and I have a question (sorry if it is something too basic but I want to know). So I have this code which is supposed to multiply every element of a vector with a number:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "IntCell.h"
#include<vector>
using namespace std;

vector<float> MatMult(int a, vector<float> & b)
{
vector<float> c;
int i;
for(i=0;i<=b.size();i++){
    c[i]=b[i]*a;
}
return c;

}

int main()


{int a=3;
 vector<float> b{1,2,3,4,5};
 vector<float> c = MatMult(a,b);
 cout<<c[2];
}
```

It compiles fine, but I get Segmentation fault: 11. What is wrong about it?
Thank you!

Comment: You should iterate **until** b.size(), because vectors are 0 indexed

Comment: Check the line in your `for`, what you're calculating is not what you really want to calculate.

Comment: You never initialized `c`.

Comment: Even with the most basic of debugging, like just printing out `c.size()`, and I'm sure you could have solved this yourself.

Comment: @tkausl sorry i just modified it, yes it should be c[i]=b[i]*a; but it still doesn't work.

Comment: @NathanOliver what do you mean?

Comment: @SSSJ How are you going to set `c[i]` if the vector has no elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`vector<float> c;` creates an empty vector.  You then uses it in `c[i]=b[i]*a;` which is undefined behavior as `c[anything]` does not exist.

You need to make `c` the same size as `b` if you want to use `c[i]=b[i]*a;`.  That would look like:

```
vector<float> MatMult(int a, vector<float> & b)
{
    vector<float> c(b.size());

    for(int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++){
//                   ^ use < here since b[b.size()] is out of bounds
        c[i]=b[i]*a;
    }

    return c;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a reasonably current compiler this is simpler. Take the `vector` by value and multiply using a **range-based for loop** to avoid out-of-range bugs.

```
vector<float> MatMult(int a, vector<float> b)
{
    for (float& value : b) {
        value *= a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

This can be made more generic as a template function. Note the code below almost certainly can be improved.

```
template <typename T>
vector<T> MatMult(int a, vector<T> b)
{
    for (auto& value : b) {
        value *= a;
    }
    return b;
}
```

Comment: Why not `auto` for `value` to make it easier to change in the future?

Comment: @NathanOliver: I'd probably make it a template and then use `auto`.

Comment: @NathanOliver: If `b` changes, then your function has changed, semantically, and thus you probably want to be forced to remember to re-read the function to make sure nothing else needs changing too. `auto` prevents the compiler from performing this most basic of compiler activities. The loop was designed to function over `float`s, so write `float`!

Answer (score 2):

You can't just do `c[i]` since there's no such index yet. You'd better write `c.push_back(b[i] * a)` or preallocate memory with `c.reserve(b.size())`.

What's more, `b.size()` returns the number of elements in a vector, not the biggest *index*, so you should use `i < b.size()` instead of `i <= b.size()`.

Comment: he/she is doing i<=b.size() -1, unconventional but not wrong

Comment: @ForceBru: In your defence, the question didn't have the `-1` at first.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, I hate it when askers change their questions in such a violent way. Rolled this back.

Comment: @ForceBru: :thumbsup:

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the other answers given, one way to discover right away if you are accessing vectors out of bounds is to first develop using `vector::at()` and not use `[]`.

```
vector<float> MatMult(int a, vector<float> & b)
{
   vector<float> c;
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<=b.size();i++){
        c.at(i) = b.at(i) * a;
}
return c;
```

Instead of a segmentation fault, you would have been given an `out_of_range` exception, thus giving you much more information on what the issue is.  Once you rid yourself of all of the `out_of_range` errors, you can then switch to using `[]`.

[Live Example using vector::at](http://ideone.com/ZHx5fR)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Ah yes of course.  The exception popup still has the type of exception.

Comment: @NathanOliver: Well I don't know what an "exception popup" is but your program will be terminated if you don't handle the exception and any debugger worth its salt can be used to identify what exception that is, where it was raised, etc.